# Finding the number of monotonic paths between two points, without constraint or while visiting a specific intermediate point

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations

A monotonic path from point $A$ to $B$ is a path that only includes "ups" and "rights".

If point $A$ is $(0,0)$ and $B$ is $(7,9)$, then one possible path is UUUUUUUUURRRRRRR (up $9$ times, right $7$ times). Another path could be URUUUUUUUURRRRRR.

My question is, for the first part: how many such paths from $A$ to $B$ are there?

The way I tried to solve this question was to see all the possible combinations for fitting $7$ R's into $16$ different slots. The reason why there are $16$ different slots is that I need a total of $7$ rights and $9$ ups to get to $(7,9)$ from $(0,0)$. Thus, this should be a combination problem of how many ways I can arrange $7$ rights and $9$ ups in a slot of $16$. When finding the number of combinations, I can just find the number of ways to arrange R's into $16$ different slots and ignore the number of ways to arrange U's. I tried figuring this out with smaller test cases and the answer seems to be $\binom{16}{7}$. Can someone verify this?

The second part of the problem I was trying to solve was finding how many paths go from $(0,0)$ to $(3,2)$ to $(7,9)$. To solve the second part, I ignored the number of paths going from $(0,0)$ to $(3,2)$ and focused on the number of paths going from $(3,2)$ to $(7,9)$. I used the same method in the first part and got $\binom{11}{4}$. Can someone verify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the first part is correct. Note that you're not "ignoring" the $U$'s, though -- rather, what you're doing is choosing $7$ slots for the $R$'s, from $16$ in total. And, well, the remaining slots **must** be filled with $U$'s as a result.

For the second part, you are not correct. Your answer seems to be assuming that, if a path goes $(0,0) \to (7,9)$, it must surely stop at $(3,2)$, which it does not. (Think, for instance, of a path that goes all of the way up and all of the way to the right.) Or perhaps you're thinking "there is only one path $(0,0) \to (3,2)$", which is also not correct, and you can show as much.

The correct logic is to find the number of paths $(0,0) \to (3,2)$ and $(3,2) \to (7,9)$ individually, and multiply these numbers. (After all, any path $(0,0) \to (3,2) \to (7,9)$ must cross $(3,2)$, so we can choose the overall path by choosing a valid path for the first half, and another valid path for the second half.)